# Response to DELETE method request sent using node.js never arrives

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, delete-method

I have node.js server which acts like a proxy. It recieves localhost requests and forward them to web service on another domain. GET, POST and PUT requests work just fine. 
But I have a problem with DELETE method request. It causing "Gateway Timeout - In read" error.  But web service on another domain recieves this request and executes appropriate DB sql to delete requested item. Moreover, if I send the same request using Fiddler for example, I receive an actual response.

Here is how my node.js http.request options look like:

```
{
  "host": "some.domain",
  "port": 443,
  "path": "/paht/item/id",
  "method": "DELETE",
  "headers": {
    "Host": "some.domain",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question:
Nodejs adds `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header to such `DELETE` request. And this header was causing described problem.

Answer (score 0):

smthin to do with firewall/spyware setting (check routers firewall) I had the same thing where my app worked on one pc and not on another...

Comment: all firewalls are turned off on my pc

Comment: any solution for this problem?

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho, I have removed `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header from the requset and it solved my original problem.

Comment: I did this too, but this make another throuble to my request, so i find another solution. Thanks ;)